# SharePoint Rest API across subsites

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom

I am trying to make a single rest api call from a top level site to get results from multiple picture libraries on multiple subsites. Is this possible and if not, what is the best way of approaching this.

I do have a rest api call to retrieve all subsites but I need to retrive results from libraries on a single request.

https://xxxx/_api/web/webs/?$select=title,ServerRelativeUrl"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch data from multiple list sharepoint REST API in one Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636852/fetch-data-from-multiple-list-sharepoint-rest-api-in-one-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to query multiple lists using a single SharePoint REST API call, as to fetch data from a list you have to specify its parent web and title/ID. Usually for these kinds of queries the best choice is to utilize SharePoint Search REST API ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)) or, if you can utilize some server side code, you can use the `SPSiteDataQuery` class to make fetch data from across whole sites or site collections (have a look at [this article about SPSiteDataQuery](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/spsitedataquery-share-point-example/)).

Also, have a look at this SO question: [Fetch data from multiple list sharepoint REST API in one Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636852/fetch-data-from-multiple-list-sharepoint-rest-api-in-one-ajax-call)